# Not working Steam on ubuntu 17.10

Tags: gnome, 17.10, gui, steam

I have a problem when I was trying to run Steam downloaded from the steam page nothing happened on screen. This is what Terminal is giving to me:

```
lilia@workstation-ms-7693:~$ /usr/bin/steam %U
Running Steam on ubuntu 17.10 64-bit
STEAM_RUNTIME is enabled automatically
Installing breakpad exception handler for appid(steam)/version(0)
libGL error: unable to load driver: nouveau_dri.so
libGL error: driver pointer missing
libGL error: failed to load driver: nouveau
libGL error: unable to load driver: swrast_dri.so
libGL error: failed to load driver: swrast
```

And this:

```
lilia@workstation-ms-7693:~$ DISPLAY=:0 glxinfo | grep -i direct
direct rendering: Yes
    GL_ARB_derivative_control, GL_ARB_direct_state_access, 
    GL_ARB_draw_elements_base_vertex, GL_ARB_draw_indirect, 
    GL_ARB_indirect_parameters, GL_ARB_instanced_arrays, 
    GL_ARB_map_buffer_range, GL_ARB_multi_bind, GL_ARB_multi_draw_indirect,
```

Comment: Are you in the default Wayland session? If so, what happens if you switch to Xorg?